# Strange jquery ui datepicker behavior

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

JQuery UI datepicker widget is not displaying the date correctly it looks like this:
[image]

the input code looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="DateTo" id="DateTo" class="hasDatepicker">
```

I add datepicker simply by calling `$('#DateTo').datepicker();`

Anyone have an idea why it does not display the dates correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the dates:

```
var qDates = '2009-11-01',
dateParts = qDates.match(/(\d+)/g)
realDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2]);  

$('#datePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); 
$('#datePicker').datepicker('setDate', realDate);
```

Comment: Thanks, setting the format does the trick. But still... shouldn't it display the date in some human-readable format by default..?

Comment: it will use your regional settings by default. still that date looks rather strange admittedly.

Comment: I thought that too, but as you can see in the picture in my case it does not work that way. Regional settings are en-US.